# Optimal set of shortest paths from one node to all others in a network graph

Tags: python, python-3.x, networkx, graph-theory

Let's say I have a country with a set of cities, which I represent on the network graph below as a set of nodes. Furthermore, the weighed edge between pairs of nodes, represent the distance by road between them. I'll define the capital city as node A. There is no direct route between A and C so there is no edge between them.

I want to keep all the roads in my country that represent the shortest path from the capital A to all other cities. I then want to remove all other roads. However, I want to find the solution which allows me to remove the largest distance of road possible.

If we look at my network below, the solution in this case is to remove the edge between C and D. By doing so, I can still visit B, C, or D from A at the shortest possible distance and I have removed road of length 3. If I instead removed the road between B and C, I would have only removed road of length 2, so this is not the solution I am looking for.

How might I go about solving this problem using networkx? nx.all_shortest_paths() will return two paths when I call it for A and C, but I can't figure out which path to choose when I have several options like this. Obviously there can be much more complex examples than that provided here.  So to clarify, I want to remove the largest possible distance of road not needed, while keeping each city the same distance away from the capital as they were before I started removing roads. So the sum of the edge weights removed should be a maximum.

**UPDATE**

This is how far I got with solving the problem.

```
import networkx as nx
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import itertools


# iterate over two consecutive values at once
def pairwise(iterable):
    a, b = itertools.tee(iterable)
    next(b, None)
    return zip(a, b)


# ["ABC", "DE"] -> [['A', 'D'], ['A', 'E'], ['B', 'D'], ['B', 'E'], ['C', 'D'], ['C', 'E']]
def combinations(a):
    if len(a) == 1:
        return [[i] for i in a[0]]
    else:
        r = combinations(a[1:])
        result = []
        for i in a[0]:
            for j in r:
                result.append([i] + j)
        return result


g = nx.Graph()
g.add_edge("A", "B", weight=2)
g.add_edge("B", "C", weight=2)
g.add_edge("C", "D", weight=3)
g.add_edge("D", "A", weight=1)

base = "A"
shortest_paths = [list(nx.all_shortest_paths(g, base, n, weight="weight")) for n in g.nodes if n != base]
print(("shortest_paths",shortest_paths))

shortest_graphs = []
for c in combinations(shortest_paths):
    print(c)
    g_ = nx.Graph()
    for p in c:
        for e in pairwise(p):
            g_.add_edge(e[0], e[1], weight=g.edges[e[0], e[1]]['weight'])

    size = sum(e[2]["weight"] for e in g_.edges(data=True))
    print(size)

    shortest_graphs.append((g_, size))

solution_graph = sorted(shortest_graphs, key=lambda k: k[1])[0][0]

# draw solution
labels = {n: n for n in solution_graph.nodes}
edge_labels = {(e[0], e[1]): e[2]["weight"] for e in solution_graph.edges(data=True)}
pos = nx.spring_layout(solution_graph)
nx.draw(solution_graph, pos=pos, with_labels=True, labels=labels)
nx.draw_networkx_edge_labels(solution_graph, pos=pos, edge_labels=edge_labels)
plt.savefig("solution.png")
```

Output:

```
('shortest_paths', [[['A', 'B']], [['A', 'D', 'C'], ['A', 'B', 'C']], [['A', 'D']]])
[['A', 'B'], ['A', 'D', 'C'], ['A', 'D']]
6
[['A', 'B'], ['A', 'B', 'C'], ['A', 'D']]
5
```

[image]

Comment: seem like [cs.stackexchange.com](https://cs.stackexchange.com/) might be right place for this problem, but since you want minimum path between different city then i think you need to get the median path length between different node and this might help you to remove the long path

Comment: Several comments: a) It seems highly unlikely that you would have ties in a real data set. b) You have two constraints: single source shortest path and minimum total weight. Is the latter only important when breaking ties, or do you actually want to optimize for minimum weight? 3) If minimum weight is the actual goal, then you will want to look at algorithms that compute the spanning arborescence with minimum weight, e.g. [Edmond's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edmonds%27_algorithm). IIRC, there is an implementation in networkx.

Comment: @Paul Brodersen Primary constraint: Each city has to remain the same distance away from the capital as they were before I started removing roads. Secondary constraint: Remove as much road as possible. The length of road removed is equal to the sum of the weights of the removed edges. I'm using the example of cities and roads to clearly explain what I'm  trying to do, but my actually application is more abstract. Thanks!